# Is it safe to alter these two lines of a Makefile?

Tags: c++, macos, installation, makefile

I've been trying for several days to install a [C++ library](https://github.com/asiffer/libspot) dependency for a python package I want to use. In addition to having no idea how to install something from source (when homebrew/anaconda/pip don't have what I need), I'm also working on a Mac for the first time. Woohoo!

Thanks to some excellent help in a [different question of mine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66012105/how-to-install-c-dependencies-from-source-for-a-python-package-on-mac-os/66015117#66015117), I think I'm almost there. Answers and comments on that question got me to the point where when I use `sudo make install`, I get this error:

```
Configured with: --prefix=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr --with-gxx-include-dir=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/c++/4.2.1
(standard_in) 1: parse error
Checking the headers installation directory (/usr/include/libspot)
mkdir: /usr/include/libspot: Operation not permitted
```

So that lead me to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33314242/3696204) which says that on newer macs you can't install to the /usr/ directory but should use /usr/local/. So I looked at the makefile and found these two lines:

```
###
INSTALL_HEAD_DIR = $(DESTDIR)/usr/include/libspot
INSTALL_LIB_DIR = $(DESTDIR)/usr/lib
###
```

I recon that these need to be changed to match this /local/ requirement, but I'm a bit scared to do so. Is there any danger in changing those lines to

```
###
INSTALL_HEAD_DIR = $(DESTDIR)/usr/local/include/libspot
INSTALL_LIB_DIR = $(DESTDIR)/usr/local/lib
###
```

Thanks!

Comment: "*Is there any danger in changing those lines [...]*" Hard to say without seeing what the MakeFile actually does. This sounds like the type of question you should ask whoever gave you that MakeFile. Also, on a side note, your first link takes me to a blank blocked page. Is that actually a good link?

Comment: @scohe001 Well I got the makefile directly from a github repo, which I just included a link to in an edit. There were lots of installation instructions for different flavors of linux, but none for a mac. And I just fixed the link, thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: Github supports conversations like this. You can open an issue like you'd ask a question on StackOverflow, except all of the contributors to the repo will get a direct ping/email about it. But just from a ctrl-F for those variable names, it looks like it won't hurt you to change.

Comment: Thanks @scohe001. I indeed requested some clarifications on how to install for mac OS. It's been several days of radio silence, so I thought I'd try here. I guess I'll just give it a go and see what happens ;)

Comment: It looks like that repo only has one contributor and they haven't been active on GitHub for 3wks, so you may have to wait a bit for a response. But that's just how the world of open source can work :)